# Entropy change of the surroundings

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

My textbook says:

$\displaystyle\Delta S_{surr}=\frac{q_{surr}}{T}=-\frac{q_{sys}}{T}$

So far, so good. It then goes to say:

$\displaystyle\Delta S_{surr}=\frac{-\Delta H_{sys}}{T}$ [at constant $P$]

**My question:** How is the assumption of constant pressure (for the system) justified?

Comment: In general it is not. The book is simply stating a formula that applies in a special case